# Nodejs declaration or statement expected

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to find errors on this code but I'm inposible to find it
declaration or statement expected error

```
function deleteFromGame() {
    for (var k in removefromGame) {
        if (removefromGame[k]['expire'] - time() <= 0) {
            pool.query('SELECT trade_token FROM games WHERE id= ' + pool.escape(removefromGame[k]['id']), function(err, row) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                if (row.length == 0)
                    return;

                if (row[0].trade_token == '') {
                    var offer = removefromGame[k]['offer'];
                    offer.decline((err)=>{
                        if (err)
                            return;
                        pool.query('UPDATE games SET psteamid = "", pname = "", pavatar = "", pskinsurl = "", pskinsnames = "", pskinsprices = "", ptp = "", passetids = "", trade_token = "" WHERE id = ' + pool.escape(removefromGame[k]['id']), function(er, ro) {});

                        loadAllGames();
                        sendGames(removefromGame[k]['id']);

                    }
                    );
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Can you help me with this issue, is a headache for me

Comment: You'd have a better chance of getting help if your code was properly indented and readable (like not hidden off the edge of the code window).

Comment: Could you show the error message that produced

Comment: Paste your block of code in here: http://jshint.com/ and it will show you the error.

Answer (score 1):

You should use any code style for your code, and use `tab` or `space`.

I edited your code :

```
function deleteFromGame() {
    for (var k in removefromGame) {
        if (removefromGame[k]['expire'] - time() <= 0) {
            pool.query('SELECT trade_token FROM games WHERE id= ' + pool.escape(removefromGame[k]['id']), function(err, row) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                if (row.length == 0)
                    return;

                if (row[0].trade_token == '') {
                    var offer = removefromGame[k]['offer'];
                    offer.decline((err)=>{
                        if (err)
                            return;
                        pool.query('UPDATE games SET psteamid = "", pname = "", pavatar = "", pskinsurl = "", pskinsnames = "", pskinsprices = "", ptp = "", passetids = "", trade_token = "" WHERE id = ' + pool.escape(removefromGame[k]['id']), function(er, ro) {});

                        loadAllGames();
                        sendGames(removefromGame[k]['id']);
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```